# How to detect onclick of facebook close button that appears when you click like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

In the XFBML version of the like button when you click the like button, a comments box appears where you can post a comment along with the like story. It's a dialog with "Post to facebook" and "close" buttons. I want to detect if the close button is clicked.

I inspected the button on the dialog that appears and found the "Matched CSS Rules" and found these classes:
`.uiButtonText, .uiButton input`

The button html when I inspected is:

```
<label class="_5v7 uiButton" for="u_0_6">
<input value="Close" type="submit" id="u_0_6">
</label>
```

Now tried to detect an onclick on any of these classes and ids in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '._5v7 uiButton', function(){
   alert('test');                                       
}); 
});
</script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.uiButton input', function(){
   alert('test');                                       
}); 
});
</script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '#u_0_6', function(){
   alert('test');                                       
}); 
});
</script>
```

All do nothing. Tried also to detect onlclick of input like this but it does nothing also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'input', function(){
   alert('test');                                       
}); 
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about the Facebook API, but by chance are the Facebook things being put on the page in an `iframe`? If so, you won't be able to detect events, because they don't bubble from the `iframe`, and you won't be able to access the `iframe` because it's in a different domain.

Comment: This is inherently evil. If you want to know whether a user posted a comment you'll need to use the Facebook API. If the Facebook API doesn't expose this functionality they don't want you to know.

Comment: @lan it's actually yes inside an iframe...I put the like button in an overlay and want to close the overlay when the user likes but want to take advantage of the comment feature so I i just subscribe to like event it will close the overlay and the like button before the comment box appears..that's it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Facebook Javascript SDK and Event Subscribe.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

I don't know if there are other other events you can subscribe to which are not documented. Facebook do have a reputation for not documenting some stuffs.